# Do they really sing "Як їх сдружати й навчати" in this version of "Гой, питалася княжа корона"?

Tags: фонетика, spelling

I've been trying to translate [Гой, питалася княжа корона](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQ1HzvM-xNM) into English and noticed that they seemingly diverge in the pronunciation of one word in this rendition of the song:

> Другу радочку - за колядочку:
>   Чим їх приймати, обдарувати?
>   А третю раду - за її чада,
>   Як їх сдружати й **навчати**.

I'm not hearing **навчати** there but something akin to **двинувати**. Am I wrong? What exactly do the singers sing there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [**ВІДВІНУВА́ТИ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12168&page=403), *у́ю*, *у́єш*, *док.*, *кого*, *діал*. Наділити посагом. *Багач буде вінувати кіньми та волами, Мене ненька відвінує чорними бровами* (з народної пісні); *Він мав лише півхати і дві грядки в городі, та ще й сестру мав відвінувати* (Н. Кобринська).

[Source is in pdf](http://www.library.dudaryk.ua/php_uploads/data/articles/ArticleFiles_239.pdf)

Comment: Aha, you were first :). Just some other sources: [1](//parafia.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Гой-питалася-княжа-корона.pdf#page=3), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=TukyAAAAIAAJ&q=%22відвшувати%22). And full quatrain (in this version): "Другу радочку за колядочку, // чим їх приймати, обдарувати? // А третю раду за єї чада, // як їх дружати, відвінувати". And English translation: "to give [dowry](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowry) (to dower)" (supposedly from _ві́но_ — archaic/dialectic for _викуп за наречену_ "[bride price](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_price)", _посаг/придане_ "dowry").

Comment: Ukrainian Wikipedia articles: [ві́но](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Віно) (about all meanings of _ві́но_), [при́да́не=по́саг=ві́но=ви́пра́ва=діви́зна](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Придане) (about more modern meaning of _ві́но_).